# JSP <button> onclick issue. Internal browser works, external browser doesn't

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am having some trouble with the jsp `<button>` onclick method.
The problem is that the function I have made in JavaScript works in the eclipse local browser, but once I try it on Firefox (40.0.3) or IE (11) it is as if my request objects are NULL or empty?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setValuesAndSubmit(row_id){
        document.getElementById('row_id').value = row_id;
        document.getElementById('selected_item_id').value = document.getElementById('item_id_'+row_id).value;
        document.getElementById('selected_item_name').value = document.getElementById('item_name_'+row_id).value;
        document.getElementById('selected_option').value = document.getElementById('item_selection_'+row_id).value;

        //alert(document.getElementById('row_id').value+'|'+document.getElementById('selected_item_id').value +'|'+document.getElementById('selected_item_name').value +'|'+document.getElementById('selected_option').value); //
        //Uncomment below if you want to submit the form
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Which is borrowed from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/LBJWQ/75/

My JSP:

```
<form action="http://localhost:808/BachelorProjectWSProviderWeb2/SearchResultServlet" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="row_id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="selected_item_id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="selected_item_name"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="selected_option"/>
       ... (Some more code) ...
   <button type="button" onclick="setValuesAndSubmit('<%out.print(i+1);%>')">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My servlet code, which works fine in internal browser

```
List<SPI_PROJEKT_S_DTO> resultList = new ArrayList<SPI_PROJEKT_S_DTO>();

        resultList = SPIDAO.searchPrimaryProject(SPIcode);

        request.setAttribute("resultList", resultList);

        request.setAttribute("SPIname", SPIname);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/primaryProject.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Context: I am getting some tables from a DB2 table, which I show dynamically on a JSP page. 
On each row of the table I want to be able to make a choice from a dropdown menu, and submit the result of the dropdown + the selected row to a new page.

As said, this works in the internal browser but NOT in external browsers.
Any ideas?
In both cases I get redirected just fine. But in the external the page I get to is empty, where as in the internal browser I get the wanted result.

***EDIT***
Now it seems the error is gone.
But I am still seeing differences between internal browser and external browser.

E.g.

```
<td><select id="item_selection_<%out.print(i+1);%>">  
<option>Please select</option> 
<option value="detailedInfo">Detailed information</option> 
<option value="subSPI">Sub SPI</option> 
<option value="primaryProject">Primary project</option> 
 </select>                  
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setValuesAndSubmit('<%out.print(i+1);%>')">Submit</button>
 </td>
```

When I select an option and submit in the internal browser the request.getParameter("example"); works fine.
But in the external browser these request.getParameter("example"); are empty.

My workspace setup:

[image: My workspace setup]

Comment: what error are you seeing in the developers console (firefox/chrome/IE) ?

Comment: I am getting this error in firefox:
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
   servlet.SearchResultServlet.doPost(SearchResultServlet.java:124)
...

The error points to this piece of code:
request.getRequestDispatcher("/primaryProject.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: in the web app, is the primaryProject.jsp file located directly inside the web content folder ? post the directory structure

Comment: All my .jsp pages is located directly in the WebContent folder, which is directly under my project folder.
Sorry but i don't know how to post the directory structure.

Comment: just expend the project until you are not reaching primaryProject.jsp and share that hierarchy pic.

Comment: I have added the picture as a link last in my original post.